# Best Way To Automate Importing Images From ImageShack.com to Imgur.com

Tags: images, upload

I want all images I have in ImageShack.com migrated to Imgur.com.

Is there a best automatic way to do this with apps, Firefox plugins, or GreaseMonkey Scripts?

The point here is I'm trying to avoid the time-consuming process of downloading images one by one from ImageShack.com and then uploading them one by one to Imgur.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the images from Imageshack via [Bulk Image Downloader](http://bulkimagedownloader.com/). Upload them using [ImageBot addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1174/).

Comment: I like the ImageBot addon because it's a Firefox plugin I can bring anytime with Firefox Portable.  Not sure with Bulk Image Downloader, though, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Bulk Image Downloader you probably could use [DownloadThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) Instead. It's a popular firefox extension, so in most cases it's better than downloading another application.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried it. IMHO it allows only to download low res images directly visible on Imageshark page (and not in "one click" way but you need to additional chose option like Multimedia or Pictures)